# How to convert batches of images with [H,W,C] shape into a dictionary of size [N,H,W,C]?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Preprocessed image shape and dtype

```
(240, 320, 3)
<dtype: 'float32'>
```

image_list = np.concatenate(image_list, axis=0)
It doesent work.

```
ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

my aforementioned code as follows

```py
  for count, filename in enumerate(files):
    image = tf.read_file(filename)
    image = tf.image.decode_png(image, channels=3)
    image = tf.image.resize_images(image, [240, 320])
    image /= 255.0  # normalize to [0,1] range
```

I'd like to change it into a dictionary with image["train"],image["valid"]
with image instances of size [N,H,W,C] as value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the extra dimension first.

```py
image_list = np.zeros([240, 320, 3])
print(image_list.shape) # (240, 320, 3)

image_list = np.expand_dims(image_list, axis=0)
print(image_list.shape) # (1, 240, 320, 3)

image_list = np.concatenate([image_list, image_list], axis=0)
print(image_list.shape) # (2, 240, 320, 3)
```